# Java - Passing values to a constructor without entering the values one by one

Tags: java, list, class, constructor

I need to create a list of TReadings which will be filled values that I will be extracting one by one from an Excel file.

The class in question:

```
public class TReadings {
long zone1;
long zone2;
.
.
.
long zone99;

// constructor
public TReadings (long zone1, long zone2 ... long zone99){
this.zone1=zone1;
.
.
.
}
}
```

As there are 99 parameters for this constructor, is there any way to pass values(or a list) to a constructor without entering all the values one by one?

Comment: Arrays, vectors, lists, .... any sort of collection. Always think about those first whenever you find yourself writing  `thing1, thing2` etc.

Comment: Varargs? You seem to have hinted at them ;)

Comment: You can try reflection

Comment: Irrespective of how you pass the values in, having 99 fields in a class is a code smell.

Comment: seems like a HashMap could be used here.  No need for a constructor/class.

Answer (score 0):

If `TReadings` is within your control, i.e. you can change it, you could just define a constructor like this:

```
public class TReadings {
   List<Long> zoneList;

   TReadings(List<Long> zoneList){
      this.zoneList = zoneList;
   }
}
```

Comment: Be careful. When someone passes a list to the constructor like that, the list is not copied, but its reference is stored. Changes to the original list cause the `TReadings` to change too!

Comment: Right, function which calls constructor should before every calling it (more exactly in this case before reading new values) create new list

Comment: Well, it may be opinion-based, but I think the constructor should make sure the state of its instance is protected from external modification, and not the calling method.

Answer (score 0):

You can use variable arguments.

```
public class TReadings {
    List<Long> zoneList = new ArrayList<Long>();
    
    public TReadings(Long... values) {
        for (Long val : values)
            zoneList.add(val);
    }
}
```

then you can call it by using by number of arguments:

```
new TReadings(1L, 23L);
new TReadings(1L, 22L, 44L, 87L, 5L);
new TReadings(99L);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public class TReadings {
    
    List<Long> zones;

    public TReadings(List<Long> zones) {
        this.zones = zones;
    }      
}

//and to call it
List<Long> zones = new ArrayList<>();
zones.add(1);
//...
zones.add(99);
TReadings readings = new TReadings(zones);
```